# How to execute a macro in command mode?

Tags: macro

The contents of register `w` are `xx`. When I try to run the following command:

```
:for i in range(1,10) | if i > 5 | @w | endif | endfor
```

It throws an error saying that `E492: Not an editor command xx`.
How do I execute the macro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:h execute` combined with `:h normal`, like so:

```
:for i in range(1,10) | if i > 5 | exe "normal @w" | endif | endfor
```

Short explanation: `execute`/`exe` runs it's argument as an `Ex` command and `normal` behaves as you would press given symbols/keys yourself.

Comment: Or in this case, just `normal @w`. Or `normal! @w`, in case you have `@` mapped.

Comment: For some reason `normal @w` didn't worked for me, but I didn't want to focus on that if using `exe` did the trick